# Filledcurves style---Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, figure

I have two curves that intersect at one point, I used the `filledcurves` style to fill the area between the two curves using the following:

```
plot "test_data31.txt" using 1:2:3 with filledcurves lc 5 notitle,\
    '' u 1:2 with lines lc -1 notitle,\
    '' u 1:3 with lines lc 3 notitle
```

which yields to the following figure:
the two curves are in blue and black lines and the filled area in cyan

[image]

My question is: What I need to change in the code above to have also the area below the intersection point (the little white zone) filled?

Comment: What does wolfram-mathematica tag has to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the positions of those two "cusps" in your plot (let's say they are located at `x_0` and `x_1` with `x_1 > x_0`), you could perhaps use:

```
plot "test_data31.txt" using 1:(($1<x0||$1>x1)?min($2,$3):1E-4):(max($2, $3)) with filledcurves
```

Here, the "constant" `1E-4` was chosen sufficiently small so that it is outside the `y-`range of the plot. Effectively, `filledcurves` is applied to two curves:

1. `max($2,$3)` - maximum of the two data columns
2. `(($1<x0||$1>x1)?min($2,$3):1E-4):(max($2, $3))` - minimum of the two data columns of interest outside of the "intermediate region" `[x_0,x_1]`, constant value of `1E-4` inside `[x_0,x_1]`

Answer (score 0):

In principle, @ewcz's solution points to the right direction, however, it doesn't show how to get to the points `x_0` and `x_1`. I assume you don't want to find them manually.
Furthermore, with this method of simple `min()` and `max()` and `ymin` between `x_0` and `x_1` the fill is not exactly limited by the curves.
If you have enough dense datapoints the difference might be negligible, but if you only have a few datapoints the fill is not what you would like to see.

**Script:**

```
### filledcurves to threshold value
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 0    15    19
 1     4    12
 2    -4     8
 3     3     6
 5     7     3
 6     9    -1
 7    11     4
 8    15    11
EOD

set yrange [0:]
set key noautotitle

colX  = 1
colY1 = 2
colY2 = 3
ymin  = 0

min(a,b) = a<b ?  a : b
max(a,b) = a>b ?  a : b

# Version 1: 
set title "Version 1: too simple, for some cases maybe sufficient"
x0 = NaN
stats $Data u (x=column(colX), y1=column(colY1), y2=column(colY2), \
               y1<ymin && x0!=x0 ? x0=x : 0, y2<ymin? x1=x : 0) nooutput
minF(colX,colY1,colY2) = column(colX)>=x0 && column(colX)<=x1 ? ymin : min(column(colY1),column(colY2))
maxF(colY1,colY2)      = max(column(colY1),column(colY2))

plot $Data u 1:(minF(1,2,3)):(maxF(2,3)) w filledcurves fc rgb 0xffcccc, \
        for [col=2:3] '' u 1:col w lp pt 7

pause -1

# Version 2:
set title "Version 2: better, but still not perfect"
x0 = NaN
stats $Data u (x=column(colX), y1=column(colY1), y2=column(colY2), \
               y1<ymin && x0!=x0 ? (x0=x,y00=y1) : 0, y2<ymin? (x1=x,y01=y2) : 0) nooutput
minF(colX,colY1,colY2) = column(colX)>=x0 && column(colX)<x1 ? y00 : column(colX)==x1 ? \
                         y01 : min(column(colY1),column(colY2))
maxF(colY1,colY2)      = max(column(colY1),column(colY2))

plot $Data u 1:(minF(1,2,3)):(maxF(2,3)) w filledcurves fc rgb 0xffcccc, \
        for [col=2:3] '' u 1:col w lp pt 7

pause -1

# Version 3:
set title "Version 3: as expected"
c1min(col) = (y1=column(col), $0==0 ? y10=NaN : y1<ymin ? y10=y1 : 0, y10==y10 ? y10 : y1 )
c1max(col) = (y2=column(col), $0==0 ? y20=NaN : y2<ymin ? y20=y2 : 0, y20==y20 ? y20 : y2 )

c2min(col) = (y1=column(col), $0==0 ? (y10=y11=NaN) : y1<ymin ? \
             y10=y1 : 0, y10==y10 && y1>ymin ? y11=y10 : 0, y11==y11 ? y1 : y10 )
c2max(col) = (y2=column(col), $0==0 ? (y20=y21=NaN) : y2<ymin ? \
             y20=y2 : 0, y20==y20 && y2>ymin ? y21=y20 : 0, y21==y21 ? y2 : y20 )

plot $Data u 1:(c1min(2)):(c1max(3)) w filledcurves lc rgb 0xffcccc, \
        '' u 1:(c2min(2)):(c2max(3)) w filledcurves lc rgb 0xffcccc,\
        for [col=2:3] '' u 1:col w lp pt 7 lc col
### end of script
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Little "drawback" of version 3, if you are using semitransparent fillcolors you will see the overlap which, however, in some cases might be even desired.